# Pagination Retaining User Specified Result Per Page in PHP

Tags: php, pagination

Good day coders. Please I need help with my pagination code. I have a perfectly working pagination but there is a preset variable $pageNo that controls the number of result row displayed. I did something which works(I will post the code below shortly) but once I click on page two, the value of $pageNo goes back to the default and follows the initial preset. How can i solve this? The problem is with how to retain the new value of $pageNo set by the user

Here is the code of what I did...

```
$pageNo = (int)$result->getPageNumber();

if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'Change')
{
    $pageNo = filter_var($_POST['pageno'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $_SESSION['pageNo'] = $pageNo;

    if(isset($_SESSION['pageNo']))
    {
        $pageNo = $_SESSION['pageNo'];
    }
    else{
    $pageNo = (int)$result->getPageNumber();
    }
}
```

Here is the code that gives user the option

```
<form action="." method="post" style="float: right;">
<select name="pageno" class="form-control">
<option value="1" <?php if(isset($pageno) && $pageno == "1") echo 'selected';  ?> >1</option>
<option value="25" <?php if(isset($pageno) && $pageno == "25") echo 'selected';  ?> >25</option>
<option value="50" <?php if(isset($pageno) && $pageno == "50") echo 'selected';  ?> >50</option>
<option value="100" <?php if(isset($pageno) && $pageno == "100") echo 'selected';  ?> >100</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Change" class="mybutton radius" />
</form>
```

Comment: You are only fetching the value from your session, if this form was actually submitted. Instead, you should of course fetch it outside of that - so that it is actually available, when you don’t submit this form on the next page, but are navigating using only your pagination links again.

Comment: Are you starting a session with `session_start()` at the start of your script? Otherwise `$_SESSION['pageNo']` will always return null

Comment: (And if you wanted this pagination to work independently for different pages, that the user might have opened simultaneously in different tabs – then that value would not belong into the session in the first place, you would have to append it directly to the pagination links instead.)

Comment: @pancheke, Yes there is session_start()

Comment: @CBroe, can you elaborate your points with an example?

Comment: I made a revision and it's working now. thank you.